# UITableViewCell stored in other array

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, uitableview

I have one array(arrData) and UITableViewCell reload arrData. arrData stored in web service array of objects.
UITableViewCell in a two label and one image, label and image load data by arrData. so all label and image reload in same array but i want to reload different-different array each label and image.

## ViewController

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MemberTableViewCell.h"
#import "member_details.h"

@interface ViewController ()
 {
NSArray *arrData;
 }

@end

@implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self.tabel_view setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];

NSURLRequest *req=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://edutimeapp.com/toshow/chamber-of-commerc/ws/fetch_member.php"]];
response =[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];

 }

 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
 {
[response appendData:data];
NSLog(@"error receving data %@",response);
}

   -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
   {

  }
 -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {

     NSError *error;

    NSLog(@"Error in receiving data %@",error);
    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&error];
  NSLog(@"response data %@",json);
  
   NSArray *status = json[@"status"];
   arrData = status;
   [self.tabel_view reloadData];
    }


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
  NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *selectedRows = [tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
if (selectedRows && [selectedRows containsObject:indexPath]) {
    
    return 127.0; // Expanded height
}

return 50.0; // Normal height
 }


 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
return 1;
 }
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
return [arrData count];
 }



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

MemberTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ht"];
if (cell==nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}



cell.name.text= [[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"business_category_name"];
cell.title.text= [[[[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"business_details"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"name"];
cell.email.text=[[[[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"business_details"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"email"];

cell.image_view.image  = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"business_details"]objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"img_url"]]]];

return  cell;

 }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[self updateTableView];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[self updateTableView];
}

- (void)updateTableView
{
[self.tabel_view beginUpdates];
[self.tabel_view endUpdates];
 }
@end
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, provide the data contained in arrData. Also let us know that are you using prototype cell or custom cell with xib?

Comment: @BharatModi custom cell with storyboard and i will edit my question.

Comment: @BharatModi I will updated my question please again check. thnx

Comment: Why you are loading cell from nib then? If you are using prototype cell then your cellForRowAtIndexPath should be like below,                                   cellIdentifier = @"cellReviews";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];                 Have you logged the arrData, provide the content of the same.

Answer (score 0):

## try this code

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
{
IBOutlet UITableView *tbl;
NSMutableData *response;
NSMutableArray *Arrdata;
NSMutableArray *ArrySubData;
}
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
Arrdata=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
ArrySubData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[tbl setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
NSURLRequest *req=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://edutimeapp.com/toshow/chamber-of-commerc/ws/fetch_member.php"]];
response =[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[response appendData:data];
NSLog(@"error receving data %@",response);
 }
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 {
 }
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSError *error;

NSLog(@"Error in receiving data %@",error);
NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&error];
NSLog(@"response data %@",json);
    NSArray *status = json[@"status"];
Arrdata = status;
NSLog(@"%@",Arrdata);
[tbl reloadData];
 }
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
 ArrySubData=[[Arrdata objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"business_details"];
return ArrySubData.count;
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@",[[Arrdata objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"business_category_name"]];
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 25;
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{

UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20);
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Bold" size:13.0];
myLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
myLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:70.0/255.0 green:82.0/255.0 blue:88.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
myLabel.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[headerView addSubview:myLabel];
return headerView;
 }
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
 if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 }
 UIImageView *ImgBrands = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:101];
 UILabel *lblName = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:102];
UILabel *lblEmail = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:103];
UILabel *lblPhone = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:104];

ArrySubData=[[Arrdata objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"business_details"];
NSString *strName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[ArrySubData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]];
NSString *stremail=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[ArrySubData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"email"]];
NSString *strphone=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[ArrySubData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"phone"]];
NSString *strimage=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[ArrySubData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]];

lblName.text=strName;
lblEmail.text=stremail;
lblPhone.text=strphone;
ImgBrands.image  = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strimage]]];
return  cell;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[self updateTableView];
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[self updateTableView];
}
- (void)updateTableView
{
[tbl beginUpdates];
[tbl endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: you can show business_category_name in section and adreess,mobile,email and image  show in cell